# python unusual textfile to database: strategy

Tags: python, sql

I am pretty new to Python, so I like to ask you for some advice about the right strategy.
I've a textfile with fixed positions for the data, like this.
It can have more than 10000 rows. At the end the database (SQL) table should look like this. [File & Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6cRM.jpg)

The important col is nr. 42. It defines the kind of data in this row.
(2-> Titel, 3->Text 6->Amount and Price). So the data comes from different rows.

QUESTIONS:

1. Reading the Data: Since there are always more than 4 rows
   containing the data, process them line by line, as soon as one sql
   statement is complete, send it OR:read all the lines into a list of
   lists, and then iterate over these lists? OR: read all the lines in
   one list and iterate?
2. Would it be better to convert the data into a csv or json instead of preparing sql statements, and then use the database software to import to db? (Or use NoSQL DB)

I hope I made my problems clear, if not, I will try.....
Every advice is really appreciated.

Comment: What type of SQL platform are you using? (MSSQL, MySQL)

Comment: @RichardBoyce: Thats should be open, personally I use MySQL(or MariaDB). With NoSQL could be MongoDB.

Comment: Most of your complexity is likely to come at the reading end.  Not so much the parsing of data as your needing to keep track of your state across multiple lines - i.e. how to know when have you read all you need and are ready to insert another row into the db.  the db or csv doesn't matter much.  json might help but it throws in the complexity of generating it in the first place and handling arbitrary text in the title/text sections.  agree with Cyb..., just get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is pretty simple, so perhaps you are overthinking it a bit.  My suggestion is to use the simplest solution: read a line, parse it, prepare an SQL statement and execute it. If the database is around 10000 records, anything would work, e.g. SQLLite would do just fine.  The problem is in the form of a table already so translation to a relational database like SQLLite or MySQL is a pretty obvious and straightforward choice. If you need a different type of organization in your data then you can look at other types of databases: don't do it only because it is "fashionable".

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Since there are multiple lines that contain the data for one statement, I was not sure about the right technique: going with lists or dicts , because I have to check every line for the record type(col 42) and then join the data together for the SQL-statement.

Comment: In that case you need a list of lists that you post-process later into SQL, because from the data you shared it seems that the record id's are not necessarily consecutive.

Comment: Actually they are, a row with 2 is the beginning of a "block of information", and 5 the end. The following rows with 6 indicate different prices to this block. Then it starts with 2  again, a new block. Since I have to check a certain position and process the data blockwise, I wasn't sure if this is better accomplished line by line or list by list. But Thanks, I will just start and give it a try!!